# Java IDE doesn't recognize Scanner

Tags: java, input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Input the first number: ");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input the second number: ");
    int num2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input the third number: ");
    int num3 = input.nextInt();
    int sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
  }
}
```

I am trying to run this code in both an online IDE and Visual Studio. But they're giving me this error report:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Can you tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Could you please include the full stack trace?

Comment: @Refik you've redirected something to serve as standard in for your app, and that 'thing' ends before 3 numbers show up, or, you didn't redirect but pressed CTRL+D or otherwise closed standard in. For example, you ran this with `nohup`, or `java MyApp <someEmptyOrNonExistingFile.txt`, that sort of thing.

Comment: "java.util.NoSuchElementException" doesn't mean that "Java IDE doesn't recognize Scanner". It means that Scanner *couldn't* properly read data it was asked to read. More info about reason why it happen should be in stacktrace of thrown exception. Anyway some online IDEs don't support System.in, so it is no surprise that you ware not able to use this code there.

Comment: Input the first number: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: This is the full trace.

Comment: It looks like the case when `System.in` is already closed (or IDE sees it as such/can't handle it properly). Like it was said in earlier comments your code works fine (in *proper* environment - I tested it on IntelliJ, Eclipse and even console, got no problems there).

Comment: Also works on https://ideone.com/46Eu8a (notice that there is separate section for user input in which I put 1 2 3 so sum is 6)

Comment: Thanks for all answers, in Eclipse it worked. I can't understand the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an issue with the code that would cause this issue. java.util.NoSuchElementException is thrown by various accessor methods such as Iterator, or Scanner to indicate that the element being requested does not exist. This is strange that you are receiving this error message as I have tried and tested your code and it works. It could be a bug with your IDE that you could try to reinstall to fix.